# How to render form button in Symfony 2.3?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

How can I render a single [button defined through Symfony's Forms](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-3-buttons-support-in-forms), using Twig?

Comment: Wish I could upvote editions! Thanks @HamZa.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Exactly how you render all the other form widgets e.g. if your submit button is configured like this:

```
$builder->add('submit', 'submit');
```

Then just render the "submit" form widget:

```
{{ form_widget(form.submit) }}
```